# How to parse this datetime in C# 202107201447.0900

Tags: c#, datetime

I am receiving a date, time and an offset from UTC in a string like this

```
202107201447.0900
```

So this is 2021 July 20 at 14:47 and the timezone is 9 hours before UTC (i.e. Japan).

I need to convert this into a DateTime object.

I have tried

```
var dateString = "202107201447.0900";
var dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmm.K"; //also tried yyyyMMddHHmm.zzz
var datetime = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,dateFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Both Parse and ParseExact throw an exception (System.FormatException)

```
String '202107201447.0900' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: `0900` is not a valid match for `K`, so you need to rewrite that format anyway.

Comment: probably, you need to divide parsing on 2 parts - before `dot` and after... so 1st part - you can get date and time without timezone... and 2nd part - parse timezone in custom way. BTW - what is format `N hours after UTC` ?

Comment: Split it up. Before the `.`, first four digits is time. Next 2 is day. Next 2 is month. The rest is the year. Pass the values into `DateTime` constructor. Do similar for after the `.`.

Comment: What would be the format for positive offsets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateTime string parser does not recognize an offset that is not prefixed with an explicit plus or minus sign.

In your example, the string needs to be `"202107201447.+0900"`

One way of "fixing" the input value:

```
var match = Regex.Match(dateString, @"^(\d+)\.([-+]?)(\d+)$");
if (match.Success && match.Groups[2].Value == "")
    dateString = $"{match.Groups[1]}.+{match.Groups[3]}";

var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,dateFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

There are probably better ways of doing that, but this will add a plus sign before the offset value unless there already is a plus or minus sign there.